# Hom functor from the rationals to the rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Q;\mathbb Q)$? Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$? If yes, what is the isomorphism?

Is there a reference where the hom functor is explicitly studied with concrete examples like the above one?

Comment: This is a good exercise in becoming familiar with basic properties of homomorphisms and I strongly recommend that you take some time to think about it. Can you write down some obvious homomorphisms?

Comment: Write down some obvious homomorphisms so the Qiaochu can guide to the next step.

Comment: i can see the homomorphisms multiplication by a rational $r$   i.e the homomorphism  $q\mapsto rq$ so we have a homomorphism for each $r$  and then $\mathbb Q\subset Hom(\mathbb Q;\mathbb Q)$  . The problem in this question is that  $\mathbb Q$ is not finitely generated as an additive group so we can not enumarate homomorphisms by counting them by their values on generators like we do for $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z /n\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you already know that you have at least one homomorphism for every rational number, given by "multiplication by $r$". You might also want to notice that composition of these homomorphisms coincides with multiplication of rationals; that is, you seem to have the *multiplicative* semigroup $\mathbb{Q}$ at the very least.

The question then is whether these are all the homomorphisms...

Suppose that $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is an additive homomorphism, and $f(1)=a$. This clearly tells you what $f$ restricts to in the integer (namely, $f(m) = am$). Does it tell you anything else?

Well, what is $f(\frac{1}{2})$? Whatever it is, we have:
$$f(1) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 2f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
So in fact, we *also* know what the value of $f$ is at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Can we figure out how much $f$ is at other rationals, given how much it is at $1$? What does this tell us?

Comment: i see that $f(p/q)=f(p.1/q)=pf(1/q)=p/qf(1)$ so it's easy to conclude that $Hom(\mathbb Q,\mathbb Q)\cong \mathbb Q$. Thanks.

Comment: @palio: Of course, you need to show that $f(1/q) = (1/q)f(1)$ for that argument (which, granted, is not hard).